# How do I cancel/exit or escape from PromptDialog.Choice in Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

The PromptDialog.Choice in the Bot Framework display the choice list which is  working well. However, I would like to have an option to cancel/escape/exit the dialog with giving cancel/escape/exit optioin in the list. Is there anything in PromptDialog.Choice which can be overridden since i have not found any cancel option.

here is my code in c#..

```
PromptDialog.Choice(
                 context: context,
                 resume: ChoiceSelectAsync,
                 options: getSoftwareList(softwareItem),
                 prompt: "We have the following software items matching " + softwareItem + ". (1), (2), (3). Which one do you want?:",
                 retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again.",
                 promptStyle: PromptStyle.PerLine);
```

Example:

Bot: We have the following software items matching Photoshop. (1), (2), (3). Which one do you want

- Version 1
- Version 2
- Version 3

What I want if user enter none of above or a command or number, cancel, exit, that bypasses the options above, without triggering the retry error message.

How do we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of achieving this:

1. Add cancel as an option as suggested. While this would definitely work, long term you will find repeating yourself a lot, plus that you will see the cancel option in the list of choices, what may not be desired.
2. A better approach would be to extend the current PromptChoice to add your exit/cancelation logic. The good news is that there is something already implemented that you could use as is or as the base to achieve your needs. Take a look to the [CancelablePromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs) included in the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repository. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4801b8736288a2956e5aa46c950a3940d9dcc38a/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/SettingsDialog.cs#L39) is how to use it.

Comment: I have gone through the CancleablePromptChoice in botbuilder  but i think this does not work with number input, when it shows the list i choose 1 then , again n again show the list. I tried override  ScoreMatch method, but it does not return the first item from the list. Is something missing?

Comment: I don't think the current Prompt Choice works in that way either. If you want to allow users to select by number, then you might have to update the TryParse/ScoreMatch methods to do your custom logic OR, include the number in the option. I don't think the CancelablePromptChoice is using the ScoreMatch. It was created way before that method was added. You can override that method and call it from the TryParse.

Comment: yes you are right current Prompt Choice does not work in that way. I have override the ScoreMatch in CancleablePromptChoice as below

Answer (score 2):

Just add the option "cancel" on the list and use a switch-case on the method that gets the user input, then call your main manu, or whatever you want to do on cancel

Answer (score 0):

Current Prompt Choice does not work in that way to allows user select by number. I have override the ScoreMatch function in CancleablePromptChoice as below

```
public override Tuple<bool, int> ScoreMatch(T option, string input)
        {
            var trimmed = input.Trim();
            var text = option.ToString();

            // custom logic to allow users to select by number
            int isInt;
            if(int.TryParse(input,out isInt) && isInt <= promptOptions.Options.Count())
            {
                text = promptOptions.Options.ElementAt(isInt - 1).ToString();
                trimmed = option.ToString().Equals(text) ? text :trimmed;
            }           

            bool occurs = text.IndexOf(trimmed, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            bool equals = text == trimmed; 
            return occurs ? Tuple.Create(equals, trimmed.Length) : null;
        }
```

@Ezequiel Once again thank you!.

Comment: Is there any Implementation done for PromtDialog.String or PromtDialog.Int ?