# BotFramework Modify Retry Behavior on Choice

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm building a bot that gives the user a list of options, and ideally the user would pick something off the list. A scenario would be a user looking for dining options. I give the user a list of local restaurants, after which the user can ask questions about the restaurants. PromptChoice is great for when the user asks for something that I have listed as a choice. However, if the user asks for something that is off the list, instead of prompting the user to retry their query, I would like to take the user's query and then perform a lookup to see if I have an answer to this question. How do I modify the PromptChoice retry behavior? I have already attempted this in my message handler:

```
private async Task MessageHandler(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> argument){
    string message = "";
    try{
        object obj = await argument;
        //parse message, do something
        if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string)){
            message = obj.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(TooManyAttemptsException){
        //do something else
        object obj = await argument;
        if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string)){
             DoSomethingElse(obj.ToString());
        }           
    }
    //parse the message
}
```

However, this doesn't work, and before I can do something more graceful, the bot ends up responding back to the user with my retry prompt before crashing. When I put in a breakpoint in the catch part of the loop, while I do have my breakpoint get hit, the bot has already responded to the user by the time I am starting the DoSomethingElse function. I have overriden the PromptDialog.PromptChoice class with my own PromptChoice, but even within this class, I'm not sure what to change so that I don't issue the retry prompt, but instead handle the message elsewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share more of your code?

Comment: Sure just edited it. Let me know if there is any specific part of the code you think would be helpful

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity I wanted to see the prompt choice part of your code, was going to try too reproduce :)

Comment: The way to go is to create custom prompt choice. Take a look at the question I marked as duplicate. More also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbotframework%5D+CancelablePromptChoice)

Comment: Yeah so I have overriden the PromptChoice, and, as expected, I see in the TryParse logic that I am not matching on any of the existing choices. What I wasn't sure about is how to correctly handle this failed match. I saw from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702597/how-do-i-cancel-exit-or-escape-from-promptdialog-choice-in-bot-framework/42705108#42705108 that I can handle the response differently, but I can't just return True, I need to switch behavior altogether. Would the global dialog approach be the best thing to try?

Comment: You can still return true and the value. And perform the search in the ResumeAfter<T> method where you could check if the value was part of the options defined or not

Comment: Ah okay that's a good idea. One other thing that I have found is that the reason the try-catch logic doesn't work is that because the PromptDialog actually posts a response back to the user before throwing the error: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/64d7257cde37b6b50f98dc99a88b194fe8e4029c/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L1178