# MS Bot Framework: Is there a way to cancel a prompt dialog?

Tags: botframework

Specifically the PromptDialog.Choice

When I display a list of options to the user I'd like them to be able to simply type cancel, or quit, or exit, and end the prompt. Instead, if I have 3 retries for example, the user must type cancel 3 times to exit the prompt.

Comment: You probably want to use [scorables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs)

Comment: Ezequiel Jadib offers two great solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702597/how-do-i-cancel-exit-or-escape-from-promptdialog-choice-in-bot-framework

Comment: @Nivlagx great point, we should flag this one as a duplicate of the question you mentioned

Comment: @JasonSowers Thanks, that worked way better than the other answer.

Comment: @JasonSowers Yup, spoke too soon. Scorables do not work for the PromptDialog.Choice. I'll have to do some sort of combination of both :0